# how to generate heap dump from jboss-eap-6.0

Tags: jboss6.x

Hello All,

```
how to generate heap dump from jboss-eap-6.0 ?

below link talks about JBoss AS 6.x but i am looking for jboss-eap-6.0, seems jboss-eap-6.0 doesn't JMX bean support. i know Jmap command but i am more of looking how to trigger manually  from jboss-eap-6.0
```

http://www.jochenhebbrecht.be/site/2012-12-12/java/creating-a-java-heapdump-in-jboss-6x

Answer (score 0):

Try [JVisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jvisualvm.html). It comes with the JDK, you should see it in your `bin` folder next to `java/javac`

It has options to profile and dump a running JVM. It can connect to remote JVMs, check [here](https://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html) on how to enable JMX port, if JBOSS doesn't have that by default.